# How to have primary and secondary sorting stipulations for a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have this list of lists:

```
myList = [[1, 200], [3, 200], [4, 300], [2, 200], [1, 300]]
```

And would like to know how I could sort it primarily by the second item in each nested list then secondarily by the first item.

I would like the list to end in this order:

```
[[1, 200], [2, 200], [3, 200], [1, 300], [4, 300]]
```

I have done `myList.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])` but this only sorts by the second item. I'm not sure how to have primary and secondary sorting stipulations.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, if one answer helps, think about accepting it (gray tick top left of the answer you think is the more helpful)

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator

myList = [[1, 200], [3, 200], [4, 300], [2, 200], [1, 300]]

new = sorted(myList, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0))

print (new)
```

You just need to mention the priority in itemgetter(). 1 first for the second position, then 0 for the first.

Output:

```
[[1, 200], [2, 200], [3, 200], [1, 300], [4, 300]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try sorting with both:

```
>>> myList = [[1, 200], [3, 200], [4, 300], [2, 200], [1, 300]]
>>> sorted(myList, key=lambda x: x[::-1])
[[1, 200], [2, 200], [3, 200], [1, 300], [4, 300]]
>>>
```

The above code sorts by both values, but it first sorts it by the second value, then if the second value is the same as others, it sorts by the first value.

Answer (score 1):

The `key` parameter for the `sort` method can also be a tuple, rather than an attribute or element of each object, which is usually the case. Here the items are sorted by their second element, then by their first element.

```
# Initial list
myList = [[1, 200], [3, 200], [4, 300], [2, 200], [1, 300]]

# Sort list in-place
myList.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))

# Print myList
print(myList)
```

Returns

```
[[1, 200], [2, 200], [3, 200], [1, 300], [4, 300]]
```